# getting error report ->Zend_Uri_Http->__construct

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-1.6

I have Copied live website to my localserver, i even changed n base urls . but even though i am getting the below error reports. can any one help me with what i have to do to get rid of these errord.

```
1. E:\wamp\www\spacelabs_sa\lib\Zend\Uri.php(143):
Zend_Uri_Http->__construct('http', '/sa-spacelabs.n...')
2. E:\wamp\www\spacelabs_sa\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php(726):
Zend_Uri::factory('http:/sa-spacel...')
3. E:\wamp\www\spacelabs_sa\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(313):
Mage_Core_Model_Store->isCurrentlySecure()
4. E:\wamp\www\spacelabs_sa\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(161):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->_checkBaseUrl(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
5. E:\wamp\www\spacelabs_sa\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354):
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
6. E:\wamp\www\spacelabs_sa\app\Mage.php(683):
Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
7. E:\wamp\www\spacelabs_sa\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
8. {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:5:"uk_en";}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seams like you are missing a slash somewhere in an url. It is `http:/website.com` instead of `http://website.com`

Comment: Yes it seems like your URL is not correct. I think you should try what @Marius is saying.

Comment: i used the same base url for my magento on my test server                           http:/sa-labs.no-ip.info, Even though iam getting the same error.

Comment: Have you created any virtual host for running this website on your local system?

Comment: @Pankaj yes i have created a virtual host name on my test server to run this website. Why do i need to change anything else on my hostname.

Comment: on test server means your localhost or it's a hosted server?

Comment: not localhost but a virtual server where we have hosted our website .

Comment: First change the url in magento from `http:/sa-labs.no-ip.info` to `http://sa-labs.no-ip.info/` then try it and tell me.

Comment: @pankaj: yes i have done now i am not getting any kind of error reports. but the page stood like that with blank white screen. it was not redirecting to index.php. Any further links i need  to replace.

Comment: Try to enable error reporting. You can do it from index.php just umcomment `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` just remove #.

Answer (score 0):

Change your base URL to `http://sa-labs.no-ip.info/` and if you are using SSL Certificate then make secure to `https://sa-labs.no-ip.info/`.

After doing this enable the error reporting by uncommenting `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` from index.php by just removing the `#`.